# Complete event for Dynatree/Fancytree initialization and Ajax loading?

Tags: jquery

I need a way to detect if the tree has loaded or if the adding of the new nodes has completed programmatically or if the loading by ajax has completed. So far I could not find any callback/event to do this.

postProcess event does not seems to help either.
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Just add the "complete" clause to your ajax request. It would look something like this:

```
$("#fileTree").fancytree({
        source : $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : 'http://localhost:8080' + '/MyRoute',
            dataType : 'json',
            complete : function() {
                $("#fileTree").fancytree("getRootNode").sortChildren(null, true);
            }
})
```

Here are two links that may help you:
[jQuery AJAX - Do Stuff in Success or Complete callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160482/jquery-ajax-do-stuff-in-success-or-complete-callbacks)
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/