# What is different between ajaxSuccess() and ajaxComplete() functions?

Tags: ajax

ajaxSuccess() and ajaxComplete() functions seem similar.

Can you give an example for explaining the difference between ajaxSuccess() and ajaxComplete() functions on jsfiddle?

Thanks

Comment: Already been posted, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12160482/jquery-ajax-do-stuff-in-success-or-complete-callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simpler terms, ajaxSuccess() would be called when your request successfully does what is assumed to do, means successfully rendered back from server with a 200 OK response. But ajaxComplete() is something which would be called every time a request is being made to the server, irrespective of whether it goes to "success" block of "error" block of your ajax request,the ajaxComplete() block always gets executed.